# "Dependency failed for /home" 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, dependencies, home-directory, boot-repair

I wanted to expand the home partition on ubuntu 22.04 and create some free space on windows 11. Then trying to do, accidentally change the configuration for home partition in disk manager. At some point it seemed like as a mounted ssd but couldn't fix it. Now, I am not able to log in to ubuntu. It says "Dependency failed for /home". I am not able to log-in but I can open the gnub screen by pressing ctrl+esc while booting.

Any suggestions?

thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DxZm.jpg)

Comment: Does the partition mentioned in your picture still exist (ie. partition using the UUID provided in your picture which failed to be found & thus couldn't be mounted). You won't be able to login with a GUI account if $HOME isn't available and has sufficient space.

Comment: Yeah, it still exists. I can display it in recovery mode. 
I think I need to find a way to put it in the previous directory but I couldn't figure it out. It looks like mounted "/" .